# Android + Show Imageview fullscreen for 3 seconds and then return to the corresponding activity

Tags: android, image, fullscreen

I am desperate need of your kind help,

I have 5(4+1) activities . When I click Image on Any of the 4 activities I want to Display it on the last 1 Activity, That too in fullscreen...

> That Means I have 4 activities which will appear in random, And if I click the Image view on any of the Activity , I want to display the selected Image in Fullscreen on the Final Activity

Kindly help me sending the code...
(And my plan is to use only one activity to view all the images respectively selected from before activities and will disappear after 2~3 seconds.)

As I have just Started working on **ANDROID** Projects, Any sort of help will be appreciated.Thank you.

Ok here it is ,

MAinActivity.java

```
           public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.imageView1:
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageView.class);
    i.putExtra("key1", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    startActivity(i);

    break;

    case R.id.imageView2:
    Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageView.class);
    i1.putExtra("key1", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    startActivity(i1);

    break;
```

ImageView.java:

```
            super.onCreate(b);      
    iv = new android.widget.ImageView(this);        
    Uri savedInstanceState = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("key1");        
    iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));     
    iv.setImageURI(savedInstanceState);
```

ok, I am really stuck here to Transfer the Image from One MainActivity to ImageView Activity.

Please Point out my innocense.

And in my Main.xml file , I have the related ImageView Tags .

Comment: Pleas do ask the thing that you tried and not succeed in getting it

Comment: What do you mean by `When I click Image on Any of the 4 activities I want to Display it on the last 1 Activity`? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @JJPA That Means I have 4 activities which will appear in random, And if I click the Image view on any of the Activity , I want to display the selected Image in Fullscreen on the Final Activity

Comment: Nobody will send you any code. You have to write it yourself and if you have issues with it then you can ask the question addressing that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make one activity in which you can declare one methode which is called on after 3 second and write `finish();` in that And in this activity you can pass image name to show in full screen via `intent.putExtra`

Let me know if you need code

Here is code

- In *Activity A* save the file (Internal Storage)

```
String fileName = "SomeName.png";
try {
    FileOutputStream fileOutStream = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    fileOutStream.write(b);  //b is byte array 
                             //(used if you have your picture downloaded
                             // from the *Web* or got it from the *devices camera*)
                             //otherwise this technique is useless
    fileOutStream.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

- Pass location as String to Activity B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("picname", fileName);
```

- In *Activity B* retrieve the file

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String fileName = extras.getString("picname");
```

- Make *drawable* out of the picture

```
File filePath = getFileStreamPath(fileName);
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(filePath.toString());
```

- Apply it to the ImageView resource

```
someImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

To acces drawable folder resources with name  you can use this methode

```
private void showImage() {
    String uri = "drawable/icon";

    // int imageResource = R.drawable.icon;
    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(image);
}
```

Comment: :Hi, thanks But, I have Some 8 Images Max., And can use them From Res/drawable folder itself only , Then Also will  the Above code work?